# Numpy array not getting updated

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `data3` of size `640X480`.

I have written this code to update a specific condition which works well.

```
data4=np.where((data3<=119) & (data3>110),13,data3)
```

Following is the list:-

```
b = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 150]
```

To update the data, following is the code

```
for i in range(2,17):
   data4=np.where((data3<=b[i]) & (data3>b[i-1]),i+1,data3)
```

any pointers why data doesn't get updated?

Comment: The result with `i` == 3 replaces the result from 2, and 4 replaces that and so on.  You aren't accumulated any results.

Answer (score 0):

when i=16, the condition becomes:

```
 data4=np.where((data3<=150) & (data3>150),i+1,data3)
```

of course the answer of "(data3<=150) & (data3>150)"  is False (nothing), so all the data will be replace with data3.

So, at the end of the loop, you will get data4=data3.